# Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function

Tags: reactjs

i searched for it and i think i am Breaking the Rules of Hooks but which one i dont know .. can u help me with solving it too?
the Home function was working correct when i followed react router (https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start/1st-example-basic-routing)
i just replaced it with this home function and it worked successfully

now what i want to do is to request data from the server and receive it in react js so i can display it successfully

EDIT: every thing is working Fine at express as a back end server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qapH.png)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import logo from "./logo.svg";

import "./App.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: "",
      body: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    var Vstate = Home();
    console.log(Vstate);
    this.setState({
      user: Vstate.user,
      body: Vstate.body
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <label className="username"> user is here {this.state.user}</label>
        <label className="body">body is here {this.state.message}</label>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function Home() {

  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data)
      });
      // console.log(data.message);
  }, []);
    return data;

}

function About() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState(null);

   
  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/s")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => {
        setData(data.message)
      });
    }, []);
    console.log(data);
    return <h2>{data}</h2>;
}

function Users() {
  return <h2>Users</h2>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: You can't use hooks in class components.

Comment: but i need to use props and componentDidMount .. can i use them in function App ?

Comment: either fetch your data directly inside `componentDidMount` and delete `Home`, or render a `<Home>` in your JSX and have it fetch data in `useEffect` and store it in `useState`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `App` into a function component, and then you can use hooks.

FYI hooks typically follow the naming convention of `use[theThingThatItDoes]`

So you could write your code like this, and it should work

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';

import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  const {user, body} = useFetchData();

  return (
    <div>
      <label className='username'> user is here {user}</label>
      <label className='body'>body is here {body}</label>
    </div>
  );
};

function useFetchData() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({});

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(setData);
  }, []);

  return data;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

inside of the `componentDidMount` function of a class component, you are manually calling a function component (`Home()`) instead of attempting to render it with JSX (or `React.createElement`). manually calling a functional component which uses hooks is a violation of the rules of hooks, just like the error message says.

you need to reference your functional component inside the JSX returned by your class component's `render` method (or the JSX returned by another functional component).

Comment: i tested this one and it works perfect too